# Float value giving extremely large answer (C)

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm an extremely new user of C++ and I would like to know why my calculations are producing extremely absurd results. This is the part of code I am having problems with.

```
printf("Please enter the length of side:\n");
scanf("%.f", &lengthCube);
volume=lengthCube*lengthCube*lengthCube;
printf("The volume of this cube is %.f", volume);
```

`volume` and `lengthCube` have been both defined as `float` values. A test value of 10 in this gives an answer of -13798...(a very very long number). Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `float l(0); std::cout << "Provide length:"; if(std::cin >> l) { std::cout << "L = " << l << ", V = " << l*l*l << "\n"; }`

Comment: This looks more like C than C++, and my suspicion is that `lengthCube` is not a `float`. It is impossibe to tell, though, since you didn't post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the snippet you did post doesn't contain the necessary information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format for `scanf` and `printf` - it should be `"%f"`, not `"%.f"`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` from the `scanf()` format string  (and, preferably, from the `printf()` format string, unless you know what it causes `printf()` to do).

Also, this sort of I/O is largely deprecated in C++.   Your question is really C.